# How to make a React Modal open in a new Window

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

[image]
My new modal displays under the parent modal. How to make it open in a new window/modal? Here's some of the code.

```
class ForgotPassword extends Component {
  state = {
    showModal: false,
    email: "",
    errors: {
      cognito: null,
      blankfield: false
    }
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  clearErrorState = () => {
    this.setState({
      errors: {
        cognito: null,
        blankfield: false
      }
    });
  };
```

```
 <button
    className="ui medium button is-success"
    style={{ position: "relative", left: "350px" }}
    onClick={this.openModal}>
     {t("collaborateur.attribut.bouton.soumettre")}
 </button>
 <ForgotPasswordVerification showModal={this.state.showModal}/>
```

In the modal that needs to appear, I've juste added this:

```
class ForgotPasswordVerification extends Component {
render() {
    if (!this.props.showModal) {
      return null;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways. One way is

```
class ForgotPassword extends Component {
  state = {
    showForgotPasswordVerification: false,
    email: "",
    errors: {
      cognito: null,
      blankfield: false
    }
  };

  openModal = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  clearErrorState = () => {
    this.setState({
      errors: {
        cognito: null,
        blankfield: false
      }
    });
  };
```

then in render you can pass

```
if (this.state.showForgotPasswordVerification){
return <ForgotPasswordVerification/>
}
```

Best way is to use routes. Here you can check the different examples https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start